# Why <android-sdk>/tools/proguard/lib/proguard.jar version not change?

Tags: android, proguard, crashlytics, crashlytics-android, proguard-maven-plugin

I'm using proguard.jar, retrace.jar to get a retrace from the Obfuscator.txt file.  Can someone help me on which bases /tools/proguard/lib/proguard.jar and retrace.jar files will be updated?
Or Can I take these two jars (proguard.jar, retrace.jar) static?
In my system, it's showing Proguard.jar version 4.7 for since long. Should I update it manually?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That tools location is kind of obsolete. For years, proguard has been distributed with the Android Gradle Plugin, and you can find the proguard .jar file under `~/.gradle/caches` (or the corresponding directory on your system where gradle stores its files). That's what gets executed in your builds, though newer Android Gradle Plugin versions default to R8 instead

For retrace, I have only seen the tool in that `sdk/tools/proguard` location and as such it's not the newest one.